# jQuery Wordpress Plugin Conflict - Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have some issues with plugins in WordPress.

Yesterday when I installed WooTicket Studio plugin, it has conflicts with another previously installed plugin, the Essential Grid.

He's not making requests when asked.

Debugging the code I realized that he is not able to run scripts, that appears on the screen :

> Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget 
>       /wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,thickbox,plupload,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker&ver=4.5.2

Has anyone had this same problem ? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this add the following code to wp-config:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```